# Connect Ubuntu to Internet using Android phone (tethering)

Tags: internet, bluetooth, android, tethering

I have a SIM card with huge data package. Can I use my Android phone to connect my Ubuntu PC to the Internet?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

On modern android phones, the simplest way to do this is to make a wifi hotspot with your phone and connect to that.

Comment: Sure, I did it many times, but WiFi uses much more power both in PC and in the phone. It also has longer range so is inherently less secure. Therefore while travelling I prefer to use Bluetooth rather than WiFi. My original question was explicitly about Bluetooth anyway.

Comment: I don't see a reference to **Bluetooth** in your original question.  It hasn't been edited.  The Wifi will give you a faster data rate than Bluetooth.  Also, the Wifi is very secure.  You can even hide the ssid whereas no one can test a connection they can't see.

Comment: You're absolutely right. My apologies. WiFi is indeed the easiest path.

Comment: Hiding the SSID doesn't hide your network, it's trivial for someone to spot the network with a packet sniffer. The only thing it does it stop it appearing in the list of available networks. That makes it harder to legitimately use, and no harder for someone to hack into.

Comment: I seriously do not understand the downvotes.

Comment: Indeed someone is randomly downvoting here for no apparent reasons. If anyone has a problem with the answers please comment and / or add another answer please.

Answer (score 11):

I have tested the following guide: http://www.scaine.net/site/2013/10/ubuntu-to-android-tethering-over-bluetooth/ (archived [here](https://web.archive.org/web/20180405223323/http://www.scaine.net/site/2013/10/ubuntu-to-android-tethering-over-bluetooth/)) and it works like a charm. Here are the steps:

1. Phone: make sure that you have enabled data services in the phone and that you can connect to Internet from the browser installed in the phone.
2. Phone: switch on the Bluetooth, make sure that the phone is visible and enable Bluetooth-Tethering in Tethering & Mobile Hotspot menu.
3. PC: switch on the Bluetooth (you can search for Bluetooth in Ubuntu launchpad) and add your device. Ubuntu will now set-up the device.

Both Ubuntu and the phone may ask for PIN - one device will display the PIN and you need to enter the same digits on the other device.

4. PC: your phone shall now be visible in Network Manager - click the small network icon and you should see your phone on the list. When you click the phone name Ubuntu will connect to Internet via the phone.

Voilà, you're now connected to the Internet. For details and screenshots please refer to the original blog post.

Answer (score 6):

Connect your pc to your Android phone with a USB cable and on phone's settings....more settings click on USB tethering option.
That's all now you would get internet connection on pc.

Comment: My MacBook Pro late 2016 touchbar running Ubuntu 18.10 wouldn't connect to anything unless I was within 1 pace of the router and wouldn't connect to my phone hotspot at all. You sir have saved the day. It is amazing how a phone can pass through a wifi connection over USB like this and still use it itself. I thank you