# Network DISABLED and some other issues

Tags: networking, wireless, 20.04

[image]I have Ubuntu 20.04, and it has issues with wireless connection. `Ifconfig` is not installed, but `apt-get` doesn't also work properly. Output for `sudo lshw -C` network says 'network DISABLED'. What can be the solution?

Edit:

Ouput for `lspci -knn | grep 'net' -A3` on image

`lspci -knn | grep Net -A3` doesn't show anything

`rfkill list` doesn't show anything

Adapter from `lsusb`: Bus 001 Device 004: ID 7392:a812 Edimax Technology Co., Ltd Edimax AC600 USB

Comment: Please [edit] your question and add output of `lspci -knn | grep Net -A3; rfkill list` terminal command.

Comment: Are you using a USB dongle?

Comment: Yes⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀

Comment: How could we guess that? Then post output of `lsusb`. Please post it as text, don't make screenshots of a terminal.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to install Edimax AC 600 Wi-Fi adapter drivers on Ubuntu 20.04](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1234651/how-to-install-edimax-ac-600-wi-fi-adapter-drivers-on-ubuntu-20-04)

Comment: I tried to do like in that guide, but when I try to execure `dkms-install.sh`, I receive `command not found`

Comment: Then you are doing something wrong. Are you connected to internet?

Comment: No, I'm not connected to Internet, that's why I'm trying to set up my adapter

Comment: You can't install drivers if you are not connected to internet. You should have got errors on all previous commands too, not only the last one ;-) You can use your phone connected by USB to have a network access.

Comment: I am able to install drivers from another device which is working on Windows. Is it necessary to have internet connection during the process of installation?

Comment: Yes, you need an internet connection. It is very difficult to install drivers offline. You will need to download many files and run many commands.

Comment: Unfortunately, I don't have ability to connect my PC to the Internet another way

Comment: Do you have a phone?

Comment: Yes, I have. Is there a way to connect to the Internet through it?

Comment: You can connect your phone to a PC using a USB cable and enable USB tethering ot USB modem feature.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Connect Ubuntu to Internet using Android phone (tethering)](https://askubuntu.com/questions/943300/connect-ubuntu-to-internet-using-android-phone-tethering)